# Fable III: How do you know if a rental property's decor is at it's best?

Tags: fable-3

Is there any way to tell if improvements can be made to a rental property's decor, other than the amount of rent you collect, especially when you allow Jasper to choose the decor for you based on your current inventory? Is there some blip on the UI in map mode or on the sign that I'm missing?

I believe Jasper says something like, "I can't imagine any way that the decor could be improved for this property" when he finishes a house well. Sometimes he says nothing though, so how do I really know what he did without having to inspect the property visually before and after? After all, the point is that he does it for you, if I'm going to have to look anyway...I might as well do it myself!

When Jasper replaces stuff, you can sell the stuff he replaced right, it's swapped with the newer items in your inventory? (Though the new inventory screens are easy...it seems I can only see my inventory in the pawn shops...ugh...am I wrong here?)

Lastly, can Jasper be trusted when you ask him to redecorate a property for a second time? For example, you go buy out the furniture store again with different items and then go to a property for a second go. Will Jasper replace the same items, or is he smart enough to keep from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are flags on the map.  I apologize as it has been quite some time since I last played, but from what I remember...

Red flags I think indicate that the property has damage, and it will give you an option to spend X amount to fix it up.  I believe blue flags show that it is fully improved.  I think this means that the decor is at its best, as you spend money to fix it up.

I beat this game a few weeks after it came out and I owned every property in the game (sounds difficult, but really isn't).  What was hard was keeping up with the property and sinking more and more money into keeping them afloat.

Just general advice if you haven't beaten the game yet... get as much money as possible.  You by all means are not required to do this, but you might find the latter part of the game more enjoyable with loads of cash to play with.  Point being: owning property like this will come in handy.

Comment: I had noticed the color of the flags, but I think blue just means it's fully repaired. I haven't seen red, I usually repair all of them in a city every once in a while. I've only seen yellow and blue. I've only decorated a few houses, but all my properties go to blue when I repair them. I think the only way to know is when Jasper tells you that the decor is at its best and there is no way to improve.